# Rigorous text book on algebraic topology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, book-recommendation

I learned basic algebraic topology before, contents including homotopy lifting lemma and covering space and Van Kampen theorem and etc. (**The class used Hatcher's Algebraic Topology when I took this course**)

However, I have never learned things related to homological algebra. I'm taking algebraic topology dealing with homological algebra this semester, so I wonder if there is a rigorous text on this side of algebraic topology.

Personally, I do not like Hatcher's style of text. It is not that much formal in my sense and materials are not well-ordered. (For example, he proves a very special case then after few pages, he states a theorem which is more general, then just notes there that copy the idea of the proof before he handed) I personally like rigor, formal, and axiomatic approaches even if text may seem dry. For example, I like Rudin's and Folland's and Mukres' and Dummit's and Rotman's styles of texts and etc, but I dislike Stein's and Hatcher's styles of texts.

Moreover, I have seen a post saying that "Hatcher uses $\Delta$ complexes, which are rarely used". So what would be the standard complexes? And what text develops theory using that complexes?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: have you tried google?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I googled and read posts on SE, but there are too many texts recommended, and I wanna know which one fits my taste. People who have an experience with this subject might know, so I posted this one.

Comment: See if you like [Algebraic Topology, by C. R. F. Maunder](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/maunder.pdf).

Comment: I don't agree that Hatcher is non-rigorous, but I will not argue with the rest (taste is taste). $\Delta$-complexes are indeed rarely used but are actually quite good pedagogical tools, since it allows one to think simplicially without having to actually find some (necessarily larger than you'd like) triangulation of your space.

Comment: Since you are accustomed to Rotman's style, perhaps you should check his "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology". There's also "Algebraic Topology", tom Dick.

Comment: @MikeMiller So what is the standard, at least widely using, complexes?

Comment: @Rubertos This depends on context. For the sake of algebraic topology, the most useful tool is CW complexes, and the simplicial diversion is unnecessary. (Of course, there are also simplicial sets, but that is definitely not very helpful in the context I'm talking about.) If you want a simplicial viewpoint to homology, which makes some aspects (Poincare duality, Alexander duality, ... the definition) clearer, then many authors introduce simplicial complexes. But the minimal triangulation of the torus has ~12 2-simplices, IIRC, whereas a $\Delta$-complex structure has 2.

Comment: Bredon.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Weaam Among all recommended above, I really really like that by Tom Dieck after I just skimmed it. I think I finally found one. Thank you!

Comment: It's Tammo tom Dieck not Tom Dieck.

Comment: @quid Thank you for the correction)

Comment: Hatcher is perfectly rigorous. Proving particular cases before proving more general theorems helps with intuition and actually understanding where these results come from and mean concretely. Math is not just about abstract theorems and formal proofs.

Comment: @Pedro It is **my very own opinion** that learning and researching should be distinguished. When I learn something, I prefer to study abstractly, then go back to examples and all motivations, because time is limited. This way is faster than the other way, at least for me, and I don't see any disadvantage over the other.

Comment: Has anybody read Bourbaki's (first volume) yet?

Comment: You may also enjoy May's "Concise Course in Algebraic Topology". Filling in gaps is good for learning, my issue with Hatcher is he clearly has a geometric intuition that I don't share, and thus I find his examples sometimes hard to follow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tom Dieck's *Algebraic Topology* is great. It is very rigorous, presents an incredibly wide range of topics, uses (admittedly minimal) categorical language, and gives a much more homotopical perspective on many things.

A small but large detail I always remember is that Hatcher's proof of homotopy invariance of singular homology is not very useful for generalization, but tom Dieck's, which inductively constructs a natural homotopy, leads to the acyclic models theorem, from which several other (otherwise tough) theorems follow.

Comment: I think Hatcher and  tom Dieck balance each other VERY nicely indeed. The one problem I have is the classification theorem of compact surfaces, an important concrete result,isn't covered. But this can be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Our tastes are pretty much the same. So, from my experience, I would recommend Spanier's algebraic topology.

It's highly rigorous (just like an analysis or algebra book), and many results are formulated in categorical languages. Besides, assumptions are often as weak as possible.

There are also some downsides. First, there aren't many examples, though there are some examples to illustrate some assumption is necessary. Second, I don't know why the author didn't use much of CW complexes. Instead, simplicial complexes are used extensively.

Overall, it's a very classic book. Hope you'll like it.