# Book´s on Algebraic Topology "not so much algebraic"

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, differential-topology

I´m goin to study a little of algebraic topology, I understand that the books on this subject have so much algebra -obviously- but, I think there are many levels of algebra, and indeed, there are many levels of the algebra included in the algebraic topology books, which of the books on the subject are light in the algebraic stage?, so, I have seen this question before: [Rigorous text book on algebraic topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914400/rigorous-text-book-on-algebraic-topology) and
mmmm, I think my question is, in some sense the opossite of that question, I´m looking a not very rigurous book in algebraic topology, a book that is more geometric than algebraic.

Comment: So why not read Hatcher's book as is mentioned in the linked question?

Comment: I like Bredon's book Geometry and Topology.

Answer (score 0):

Some nice fairly geometric books:

- Hatcher - Algebraic Topology
- Croom F.H - Basic Concepts of Algebraic Topology
- Fulton - Algebraic Topology - A First Course
- Munkres - Elements of Algebraic Topology
- Bott R, Tu L - Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology

Comment: None of the above mentioned books deal with the issues raised in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one .